# browserify - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, browserify

I am very new to browserify and started following documentation and youtube videos to get started.

here this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js is as follows -

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var abc = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
var button = $('<button/>').html('click me').on('click', function(){
alert('hi');
})
$('body').append(button)
```

for this we have installed jquery and aws-iot-device-sdk and i could see this folders in node_modules directory.

When i opened html file in browser it is giving the following error -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

alert has worked as expected before adding

```
var abc = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
```

Please help me in this issue.